# self.visitChildren(ctx) in ANTLR visitor root node returns None in Python

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, antlr4

As the title says: when propagating values from the parsing tree the root node returns None when I call the self.visitChildren(ctx) there. I can see that the other nodes propagate the values upside but the root node is the only that is receiving None.

I am using ANTLR 4.10.1 and Python antlr4-python3-runtime 4.10.

It prints the following when I entered 393939393 and CTRL-D:

```
Number: 393939393
Atom: {'type': 'number', 'value': '393939393'}
SExpr: None
None
```

I tried with the follow slight modification of the S-Expression parser and next I show my visitor script:

```
/*
Port to Antlr4 by Tom Everett
*/
grammar sexpr;

sexpr
/*   : item* EOF */
   : item EOF
   ;

item
   : atom
   | list_
/*   | LPAREN item DOT item RPAREN */
   ;

list_
   : LPAREN item* RPAREN
   ;

atom
   : string
   | symbol
   | number
/*   | DOT */
   ;

string: STRING ;

symbol: SYMBOL ;

number: NUMBER ;



STRING
   : '"' ('\\' . | ~ ('\\' | '"'))* '"'
   ;

WHITESPACE
   : (' ' | '\n' | '\t' | '\r')+ -> skip
   ;

NUMBER
   : ('+' | '-')? (DIGIT)+ ('.' (DIGIT)+)?
   ;

SYMBOL
   : SYMBOL_START (SYMBOL_START | DIGIT)*
   ;

LPAREN
   : '('
   ;

RPAREN
   : ')'
   ;

DOT
   : '.'
   ;

fragment SYMBOL_START
   : ('a' .. 'z')
   | ('A' .. 'Z')
   | '+'
   | '-'
   | '*'
   | '/'
   | '.'
   ;

fragment DIGIT
   : ('0' .. '9')
   ;
```

**Python 3 ANTLR visitor code**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
from antlr4 import *
from sexprLexer import sexprLexer
from sexprParser import sexprParser
from sexprVisitor import sexprVisitor

class SExprVisitor(sexprVisitor):
    def visitSexpr(self, ctx):
       r = self.visitChildren(ctx)
       print("SExpr: %s" % r)

       return r



    def visitItem(self, ctx):
        r = self.visitChildren(ctx)

        return r

    def visitAtom(self, ctx):
        r = self.visitChildren(ctx)

        print("Atom: %s" % r)

        return r

    def visitString(self, ctx):
        print("String: %s" % ctx.getText())

        return {'type':'string', 'value':ctx.getText()}

    def visitNumber(self, ctx):
        print("Number: %s" % ctx.getText())

        return {'type':'number', 'value':ctx.getText()}

    def visitSymbol(self, ctx):
        print("Symbol: %s" % ctx.getText())

        return {'type':'symbol', 'value':ctx.getText()}

def visitor_main(argv):
    input_stream = StdinStream()
    lexer = sexprLexer(input_stream)
    stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
    parser = sexprParser(stream)
    tree = parser.sexpr()
    visitor = SExprVisitor()
    output = visitor.visit(tree)
    print(output)
 
def main(argv):
    visitor_main(argv)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 1):

The root node ends with an `EOF` token, which is what is being returned by your visitor after calling  `visitChildren`. If you include this method in your visitor:

```py
def visitTerminal(self, ctx):
    # The `EOF` will now return this instead of `None`
    return '???'
```

you'll see `???` being returned by `visitSexpr`.

To fix it, just invoke the `item` in your `visitSexpr`:

```py
def visitSexpr(self, ctx):
    r = self.visitChildren(ctx.item())
    print("SExpr: %s" % r)
    return r
```

And you can make your grammar a bit more compact by using `[...]` instead of the old v3 syntax `'?' .. '?'`:

```
grammar sexpr;

sexpr
/*   : item* EOF */
   : item EOF
   ;

item
   : atom
   | list_
/*   | LPAREN item DOT item RPAREN */
   ;

list_
   : LPAREN item* RPAREN
   ;

atom
   : string
   | symbol
   | number
/*   | DOT */
   ;

string: STRING ;

symbol: SYMBOL ;

number: NUMBER ;



STRING
   : '"' ('\\' . | ~[\\"])* '"'
   ;

WHITESPACE
   : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip
   ;

NUMBER
   :[+\-]? (DIGIT)+ ('.' (DIGIT)+)?
   ;

SYMBOL
   : SYMBOL_START (SYMBOL_START | DIGIT)*
   ;

LPAREN
   : '('
   ;

RPAREN
   : ')'
   ;

DOT
   : '.'
   ;

fragment SYMBOL_START
   : [a-zA-Z+\-*/.]
   ;

fragment DIGIT
   : [0-9]
   ;
```

#### EDIT

> I didn't understand your comment about the compact grammar in [...]

I mean that the older v3 syntax `'a' .. 'z'` can be written in v4 as `[a-z]`, making it more compact.

> If I use item* instead of item what is the best way to traverse the items? ...

What you added in your comment will probably work. You could change the grammar slightly to create a `items : item*;` rule that is used by the other rules. You could also use [alternative labels](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/parser-rules.md#alternative-labels) so that you don't need the extra rules like `string`, `symbol` and `number`.

A quick demo:

```
/*
Port to Antlr4 by Tom Everett
*/
grammar sexpr;

sexpr
   : items EOF
   ;

items
   : item*
   ;

item
   : atom    #item_atom
   | list_   #item_list
   ;

list_
   : LPAREN items RPAREN
   ;

atom
   : STRING    #atom_string
   | SYMBOL    #atom_symbol
   | NUMBER    #atom_number
   ;

STRING
   : '"' ('\\' . | ~[\\"])* '"'
   ;

WHITESPACE
   : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip
   ;

NUMBER
   :[+\-]? (DIGIT)+ ('.' (DIGIT)+)?
   ;

SYMBOL
   : SYMBOL_START (SYMBOL_START | DIGIT)*
   ;

LPAREN
   : '('
   ;

RPAREN
   : ')'
   ;

DOT
   : '.'
   ;

fragment SYMBOL_START
   : [a-zA-Z+\-*/.]
   ;

fragment DIGIT
   : [0-9]
   ;
```

and if you now run:

```py
import sys
from antlr4 import *
from sexprLexer import sexprLexer
from sexprParser import sexprParser
from sexprVisitor import sexprVisitor


class SExprVisitor(sexprVisitor):

    def visitSexpr(self, ctx):
        return self.visit(ctx.items())

    def visitItems(self, ctx):
        items = []
        for item in ctx.item():
            items.append(self.visit(item))
        return items

    def visitItem_atom(self, ctx):
        return self.visit(ctx.atom())

    def visitItem_list(self, ctx):
        return self.visit(ctx.list_())

    def visitList_(self, ctx):
        return self.visit(ctx.items())

    def visitAtom_string(self, ctx):
        return {'type': 'string', 'value': ctx.getText()}

    def visitAtom_number(self, ctx):
        return {'type': 'number', 'value': ctx.getText()}

    def visitAtom_symbol(self, ctx):
        return {'type': 'symbol', 'value': ctx.getText()}


def visitor_main(argv):
    lexer = sexprLexer(InputStream('("Q" 42 /7)'))
    stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
    parser = sexprParser(stream)
    tree = parser.sexpr()
    visitor = SExprVisitor()
    output = visitor.visit(tree)
    print(output)


def main(argv):
    visitor_main(argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

the following is printed:

```
[[{'type': 'string', 'value': '"Q"'}, {'type': 'number', 'value': '42'}, {'type': 'symbol', 'value': '/7'}]]
```

Comment: Thanks, I have two extra questions:
1/ I didn't understand your comment about the compact grammar in [...]

2/ If I use item* instead of item what is the best way to traverse the items? Is this right?
`
    def items(self, ctx):
       r = []
       for i in range(0, ctx.getChildCount()):
           if ctx.item(i) != None:
            r.append(self.visitChildren(ctx.item(i)))

       return r

    def visitSexpr(self, ctx):
       r = self.items(ctx)

       return r`

Comment: @rachbova checkout my **EDIT**